# TYPO3 special CSS file for IE

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

Is there a best practice to add specific css for Internet explorer in TYPO3?

I tried this in template:

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link href="fileadmin/config/script/css/ieCSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
<![endif]-->
```

but It has no effect ...

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From official documentation: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/6.2/Setup/Page/Index.html#includecss-array

```
page.includeCSS{
  ieStyle = fileadmin/config/script/css/ieCSS.css
  ieStyle.allWrap = <!--[if IE]>|<![endif]-->  
  ieStyle.excludeFromConcatenation=1
}
```

What version of Internet Explorer are you using?

Comment: that solution works fine proble is the conditional statements did not work in IE 10 and 11 ... solved problem with js

Comment: Don't feel sorry. AFAIK IE10+ does not support conditional comments at all.

Answer (score 1):

your template normaly only gives content to include in body-tag.
The css-declarations and also your IE-Conditions must be in the header-tag.

so a solution would be to use the possibility to declare your own header data:

```
page {
    headerData {
        10 = TEXT
        10 (
            <!--[if IE]>
            <link href="fileadmin/config/script/css/ieCSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
            <![endif]-->
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: statement is printed in HEAD but css has no effect in IE

Comment: do you know: `Conditional comments are no longer supported in IE10 and IE11.` (from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment)